# SOQL to get opportunity line items using grand parent relationship

Tags: soql

I want to get the opportunity line item from opportunity and using query like below

```
Select Id, (Select Id, name From OpportunityLineItems) 
   From Opportunity 
   where id in 
     (SELECT Sales_Order__r.SO_Lookup_to_Opportunity__r.Id 
        from Shipment__c where id='a043i00000ALiByAAL')
```

and getting this error

```
The inner select field 'Sales_Order__r.SO_Lookup_to_Opportunity__r.Id' 
    cannot have more than one level of relationships
```

Do we have to use two queries to get the required output means first query to get the opportunity id ,store it in a variable and then second one to get the opportunity line items from the retrived opportunity ID

Comment: Note that `SO_Lookup_to_Opportunity__r.Id` and `SO_Lookup_to_Opportunity__c` are semantically the same value, the former adds a relationship level... You should use `__c` rather than `__r.Id` when possible (which is usually always).

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you.